# memcpy fails for struct that contains char array

Tags: c, memcpy

```
struct Frame_t
{
    uint16_t src_id;
    uint16_t dst_id;
    unsigned char num;
    uint8_t is_seq;
    char data[48];
};
typedef struct Frame_t Frame;
char *convert_frame_to_char(Frame *frame)
{
    char *char_buffer = (char *)malloc(64);
    memset(char_buffer,
           0,
           64);
    memcpy(char_buffer,
           frame,
           64);
    return char_buffer;
}

Frame *convert_char_to_frame(char *char_buf)
{
    Frame *frame = (Frame *)malloc(sizeof(Frame));
    memset(frame->data,
           0,
           sizeof(char) * sizeof(frame->data));
    memcpy(frame,
           char_buf,
           sizeof(char) * sizeof(frame));
    return frame;
}
```

with those utility function be given, if I do

```
            Frame *outgoing_frame = (Frame *)malloc(sizeof(Frame));
//   outgoing_cmd->message  contains "I love you"
            strcpy(outgoing_frame->data, outgoing_cmd->message);
            outgoing_frame->src_id = outgoing_cmd->src_id; // 0
            outgoing_frame->dst_id = outgoing_cmd->dst_id; // 1
            outgoing_frame->num = 100;
            outgoing_frame->is_seq = 1;
            //Convert the message to the outgoing_charbuf
            char *outgoing_charbuf = convert_frame_to_char(outgoing_frame);
            // Convert back
            Frame *test = convert_char_to_frame(outgoing_charbuf);
            // print test->data is "I "
```

test src is 0, test dst is 1, data is "I ", test num is d, test is_seq is 1.

So, why the data just 2 characters? 
What's the correct way to do this losslessly?

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you. But isn't Frame is a struct rather than a pointer?

Comment: @Blaze Op did the same mistake but in different place.

Comment: The size of the `Frame` structure is not 64 bytes. So `memcpy(char_buffer, frame, 64)` results in undefined behavior: you're reading past the end of the structure.

Comment: What is the need of a separate `char` buffer? You can probably treat the existing buffer as raw chars. (Also, `sizeof(char) * sizeof(frame)` is conceptually wriong. `sizeof` is like a unit, namely bytes. You shouldn't multiply them. Usually you need `n * sizeof(T)` for arrays of `n` elements of size `T`.)

Comment: @user3386109 : it could be 64 bytes if the struct is not packed, and each field is aligned to 32bit boundaries. But your point is valid - using a magic value `64` is asking for trouble if or when that assumption no longer holds. Better to use `sizeof(Frame)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
memcpy(frame,
       char_buf,
       sizeof(char) * sizeof(frame));
```

should be

```
memcpy(frame,
       char_buf,
       sizeof(Frame));
```

`size(frame)` is size of pointer. Thus you are only copying `size of pointer` bytes from array.

Comment: Also please consider the comment from @user33386109, it is serious issue which needs to be fixed.

Comment: `memcpy(char_buffer, frame, 64);` is nonsense as well.

Comment: It works after the change.  :p   Regarding the memcpy boundary issue, does ```memset(charbuffer, 0, 64)```  kindda make it better? Because even though it crosses the boundary, the memory there is 0, not some garbage values.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
memcpy(frame, char_buf, sizeof(char) * sizeof(frame));
```

makes no sense, as pointed out in comments. Multiplying sizes is not logical here.

Since `frame` is a pointer, the best thing to do in my opinion is to use `sizeof` on the thing the pointer is pointing at, since that is what is being copied (into):

```
memcpy(frame, char_buf, sizeof *frame);
```

This also mildly "locks" the number of bytes being copied to the size of the destination buffer, without repeating the type name, which can be nice.

Also remember that `sizeof` is not a function, the parentheses are only needed when the argument is a type name since they are part of the argument (which looks like a cast in that case).